# Android app question: services?

Tags: java, android, web-services

I am currently programming an app that is supposed to get the users' calls and SMSs log and send them to a remote mysql DB.

I have a preferences screen and a checkbox for calls and another for sms logging and I want that when the user clicks in the checkboxes and then saves the preferences clicking a button, the logging starts to work (depending on whether the checkboxes were clicked or not).

My question is, should I implement each of the logging feature in services? 
Remote or locals?
I'd like the logging working ALWAYS until the users unticks the checboxes and saves preferences.
Should I send the data to the DB every x hours, or just storing everything in a SQLite DB in Android and then sending everything by the end of the day?

This is my first android app and as you can see I have no idea :)

Thanks everybody for your help!
Cheers

Comment: You can use local services and it is better you can send the data at the end of day(you can implement this logic as your requirement)

Comment: but, if I want to have two services doing that in the background, should I move them to an AsynTask, or just make them run as services in the foreground? I still do not get the difference between both very clear..

Comment: hey check it once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264383/difference-between-service-async-task-thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am finally using a remote service, as I want the service to be running even though the application might not be running, and will just send the data every 24h, so much better.
Thanks for your help!