# Android service stopps the main UI thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, bluetooth, android-service

There is android service listening for bluetooth socket connection.

This connection is realized in permanent loop where commands are received.

This service is started and bounded in activity `onStart()` with:

```
 intent.putExtras(b);
        getActivity().startService(intent);
        getActivity().bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

any idea why the main thread is getting stopped?

Comment: because main thread doesn't like sockets ..

Comment: A `Service` runs on the main thread unless told otherwise

Comment: You have to run that off of the UI thread, you will likely have to use a `Handler`. Reference this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958408/executing-asynchronous-task-from-service-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Because like you said, you have a permanent loop in your main thread. If no bluetooth connections come through, it will wait forever and stall your application.

Use the `Runnable` thread class and spawn your bluetooth service on another thread so the UI can still run even if no bluetooth connections come through.