# what is best way to download a file in android application

Tags: android, multithreading, download

I would like to download a pdf file(or any file type) from my android application
I want to know waht is the best solution :
AsynTask, Thread, Service

Thanks for your help

Comment: `AsyncTask` if the download is small, taking max a few seconds. `Thread` if it is larger, but you don't expect/will handle the Activity losing focus during the download. `Service` if you expect your activity to be closed by the user, but want to continue downloading in the background.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/3264383/3565972

Comment: i have used a thread with a notification that shows the progress of the file download but when i change the activity i got a NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using an AsyncTask not to block the UI thread while the download takes place, and you can do the download itself using an HttpURLConnection.

There are plenty examples here in SO.

Comment: When i use AsyncTask i have the following expection : android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: It's not recommended following other post